# How do I return a 401 authentication error to a RestSharp client?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, restsharp, http-error

In my Mvc Api controller, if the user cannot be authenticated I throw an HttpException 401.  However, the RestSharp client seems to translate this into a Http 500 status code.

I want to be able to throw HttpExceptions from my Mvc controller, and have the RestSharp client preserve the original error in its StatusCode property.

Also, I notice if the server is not up, when the RestSharp client makes a request, the reponse has a status code of 0, and a response code of Error.  Should the RestSharp not return a 404 http error code instead?

What I really need is a bit of documentation on how RestSharp works with HttpCodes.

Updated with code in my api controller:

```
throw new HttpException((int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, AuthenticationError);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been able to investigate this issue myself.  Forms Authentication is set on the web app which means that when a HttpUnauthorizedResult is returned from the controller, MVC kicks in and redirects to the login page. This has the effect of the client assuming that no errors occurred.

I resolved this by using the **aspnet.suppressformsredirect** nuget package, and add the suppress flag into the response for authentication.

Comment: Right @jaffa, this should be the accepted answer for MVC 4. But how lame is it that we have to download something just to return a 401? Ridiculous.  My just-as-lame workaround is to send a 403 Forbidden.  (See my answer).

Answer (score 12):

Have you verified that you really return 401 to the client? ASP.NET MVC got some strange error handling sometimes.

Try to return a `HttpUnauthorizedResult` instead. [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpunauthorizedresult%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

Comment: I've updated my post with code example. The controller serves json, so would using HttpUnauthorisedResult work correctly? Am I doing the right thing here?

Comment: My answer still apply. I find it more likely that ASP.NET MVC handles your `HttpException` incorrectly (and return a 501) than that `RestSharp` converts a 401 to 500

Comment: This seems to break the httpcodes then. I won't ever be able to display the correct errors back to the user. Mvc should send the correct 401 back to the client, in this case RestSharp. Is there any way round this?

Comment: Use the action result `HttpUnauthorizedResult `  from your authorization filter (or the controller action). It's an action result that is included in ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Still no luck with this, can someone try and reproduce this problem with ASP.Net MVC and RestSharp. I'm raising http errors and they're getting lost somewhere along the way.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two ways to return a 401 in MVC.

```
return new HttpUnauthorizedResult("Unauthorized");
```

or

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(401);
```

Answer (score 2):

Lame, lame, lame that we have to download a NuGet package to return a 401!  My workaround is to respond with a 403 Forbidden with an explanation:

```
throw new HttpException((int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, 
  "Please log in as user " + UserId + " and try again.");
```

Not semantically correct, but is less work, less ongoing maintenance, and less risk.